# Contact Android App via USB

Tags: android, winforms, usb

I built a app for rural activities and monitoring/administration.

My app collects alot of data during the day and needs to send it to the cloud for processing and analysis. In a regular 8 hour of work day it can collect up to 2Gb of data (most in form of pictures/video)...

Turns out that alot of my users are not served by WIFI (its a app focused on rural activities, so...) but they do have access to a physical pc/notebook with broadband... So I'm thinking about building a windows forms app that would detect the USB plugged-in android device, "send" a generic export data command via usb so the android app would send the data to the winForms app, and then, send it to the cloud...

My question is: How can I "send" this command?!? (the app being open at the sync time is not a unreasonable request)...

Answer (score 2):

Store all your data on the `SDCard` and call this command once it has been connected to the computer:

`adb pull /sdcard/yourdirectory C:\dump`

And finally modify your `WinForms` app to grab these files.
I don't see any other method.

Comment: that would require a 2 step process where the user would have to go to the app and click a "export" button of some sort right? And, what would happen if there were 2 or more devices connected?!?